# How to use default props with Redux props?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was trying to make a "photo galley app" where each image is a "button" that toggle on the boolean property for Modal tag. The problem is that the images are rendered by a FlatList which pass props to component "GenerateImage.js", but at the same time, I need to pass the state and dispatch function as a parameter as well.

File who render the FlatList:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import GenerateImage from '../components/GenerateImage'
import commonStyles from '../commonStyles'
import Modal from '../components/Modal'

const Photos = ({ params }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Modal isVisible={params.showFullImage} />

        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.button}>Hoje</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.button}>Mês</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.button}>Ano</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.button}>Álbuns</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <View style={{ flex: 30 }}> 
            <FlatList data={params.images} keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
            renderItem={({item}) => <GenerateImage {...item} />} numColumns={2} />
        </View>  
    </View>
  )
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonsContainer: {
        flex: 3,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#1c2431',
    },
    touchContainer: {
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#439ce8',
        borderRadius: 30,
        width: 65,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: 5
    },
    button: {
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: commonStyles.Font,
        fontSize: 14
    }
})


export default connect(state => ({ params: state[0] }))(Photos)
```

GenerateImage.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    PixelRatio,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'



const GenerateImage = (props, {param, dispatch}) => {
    
    function toggleModal(param) {
        return {
            type: 'TOGGLE_MODAL_ON',
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => dispatch(toggleModal(param))}>
                    <Image source={props.image} style={styles.imgContainer} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginHorizontal: 4
    },
    imgContainer: {
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.48,
        //borderRadius: 8,
        //flex: 1,
        //orderWidth: 1,
    },
    image: {
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        aspectRatio: PixelRatio.get()
    },
})

export default connect(state => ({ param: state[0].showFullImage }))(GenerateImage)
```

So, how can I pass both data?

Comment: What do you mean by I need to pass the state and dispatch function as a parameter as well? You need to pass it to toggle modal or where?

Comment: Thank you for your availability. So, i need the state and dispatch for toggle a boolean property (wich is stored on redux storage), to true in the moment that the user press the image, and with this property i would pass its value for modal visibility.

Comment: it seems so overkill for such simple thing.. I'd just use the ```useState``` hook for holding ```isToggled = true / false``` and  ```currentImage = null / defaultImage ``` why would you bother storing an image and toggle status in redux anyway

Comment: Normally i'd use the useState, but i can't change the value of the state from another file. I've tried so many things and no one of them worked

Comment: If so then your action in action creator for redux should look like this: ```return { type: "TOGGLE_MODAL_ON", image: yourImage }``` and then in the reducer you should set the state to the ```image``` variable passed in ```action``` that's pretty much the same way you would use your setState but you just move it to the reducer